# SQL error only on Select Into - Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am getting the following error while trying to select the below data into a temporary table. Please excuse the mix of join styles, I did not write the base query.

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
(47 rows affected)
```

This does **not** occur if I just run a select statement on the below query. What this should be doing is taking the value in `E.QTY_PO` and subtracting the Summed value in `F.QTY_VCHR_CNVT`, and in cases where this comes out to be `NULL` then I want it to be a value of 0 so that the math expression still works. Why is this getting the warning when trying to insert into the temp table, but not when I just perform a Select on it?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID
INTO #TEMP_PO_ID
FROM PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE
     INNER JOIN #ITEMS ITM ON ITM.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_PO_LINE.INV_ITEM_ID
     INNER JOIN (SELECT (E.QTY_PO) - ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(F.QTY_VCHR_CNVT), 0), 0) AS QUANTITY,
                        PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT,
                        PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID,
                        PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR
                 FROM PS_PO_LINE_SHIP E,
                      PS_PO_LINE PS_PO_LINE
                      INNER JOIN #ITEMS ITM ON ITM.INV_ITEM_ID = PS_PO_LINE.INV_ITEM_ID
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PO_LINE_MATCHED F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                                          AND F.PO_ID = PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID
                                                          AND F.LINE_NBR = PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR
                 WHERE E.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT
                   AND E.PO_ID = PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID
                   AND E.LINE_NBR = PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR
                   AND PS_PO_LINE.CANCEL_STATUS NOT IN ('X', 'C')
                 GROUP BY E.QTY_PO,
                          PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT,
                          PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID,
                          PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR
                 HAVING ((E.QTY_PO) - ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(F.QTY_VCHR_CNVT), 0), 0)) > 0) QTY ON QTY.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                                                                          AND QTY.PO_ID = PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID
                                                                                          AND QTY.LINE_NBR = PS_PO_LINE.LINE_NBR,
     PS_PO_HDR PS_PO_HDR,
     PS_ITM_CAT_TBL B
WHERE B.CATEGORY_ID = PS_PO_LINE.CATEGORY_ID
  AND B.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT)
                 FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL BB
                 WHERE BB.SETID = B.SETID
                   AND BB.CATEGORY_TYPE = B.CATEGORY_TYPE
                   AND BB.CATEGORY_CD = B.CATEGORY_CD
                   AND BB.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID
                   AND EFFDT <= GETDATE())
  AND PS_PO_LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT = PS_PO_HDR.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND PS_PO_LINE.PO_ID = PS_PO_HDR.PO_ID;
```

Comment: `Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation` isn't an error, it's an informational message,

Comment: Some other notes, however: Why are you "mix and matching" ANSI-92 explicit JOINs and ANSI-89 implicit JOINs here? There is no reason to be using the latter anymore when the former has been around for **30 years**. Also *please* get into the habit of using meaningful and useful aliases. Why use `B` for `PS_ITM_CAT_TBL`?  The only place `B` appears is in the suffix `TBL`; which isn't *really* part of the object's name as it's just saying it's a table (such suffixes really aren't needed either). Why alias `PS_PO_HDR` as `PS_PO_HDR` and `PS_PO_LINE` as `PS_PO_LINE` ? They are the same names.

Comment: I understand it's a Warning - however is it affecting/changing the output in any way because of the warning?

Comment: No, it isn't changing the output. If you want to suppress it, `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`

Comment: ok, and I'm curious why I only get the warning when I try to SELECT INTO the temp able, but not when I just do a straight SELECT FROM  ?

Comment: Different executions plans, perhaps? The message is shown when at least one `NULL` value appears in an expression within an aggregate function; you have several so it could be any of them.

Comment: ok, is there any way to change the expression `ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(F.QTY_VCHR_CNVT), 0), 0)` to prevent this from occuring?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent it from occurring? Why does it matter? @AaronBertrand has already told you how to suppress the message.

Comment: I'd just like to know if I could have changed the syntax to prevent this

Comment: It's not something that *needs* preventing though, @Nick .

Comment: `ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(F.QTY_VCHR_CNVT), 0), 0)` Let's discuss. You sum a column. If the sum is zero, you convert it to null, then you convert the null back to zero. Does that make sense to you? Ultimately you only select PO_ID so the entire complex query can likely be changed significantly to make it more efficient and less complex. This looks like a copy/paste of a very different query that serves a different purpose and then modified a bit

Comment: Sql server 2014, wow. Those where the days.